# Should these DRM questions be merged?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

As far as I can see, these two questions about [advantages](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/457/136) and [disadvantages](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/456/136) of DRM should be merged, because the possible answers are very likely to be the same, making the two questions duplicates.

As is explicitly stated, expected answers should provide links, facts and explanations that I strongly feel will be the same for both of them.

EDIT: these two also seem very closely related to [this one](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/425/how-does-drm-impact-the-sales-of-ebooks), which already has answers that potentially are the same requested for the two new ones.

Comment: The third one is a partial case of one of them (e.g. any answer to it would fit mine, but not every answer to mind fits the older one)

Comment: "I strongly feel will be the same for both of them." - could you please provide examples? I don't think that an advantage or disadvantage would SHARE a fact proving both of them?

Comment: I was thinking that a study about this, or the personal experiences of an author, could serve as a proof of the general effects of DRM regardless of the positive or negative outcome, and that the question would be more informative, concise and clear if all the responses were in one place. After all, I suppose that an author will ask himself "how DRM will affect my sales" in an inclusive way, so to speak. Anyway, that's just my point of view of course.

Answer (score 5):

No, they should not be merged. They are looking for specific answers at different ends of the spectrum.